# Eclipse Java compiler infers the wrong generic type?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac, ecj

I wonder if this is a bug in ECJ or a valid interpretation of the JLS.

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class GenericsTest {
    public void testInference() {
        Set<Object> set1 = getCollection(HashSet::new);
        Set<Object> set2 = getCollection2(HashSet::new);
    }

    public static <E, C extends Collection<E>> C getCollection(Supplier<C> collectionSupplier) {
        return collectionSupplier.get();
    }

    public static <E, C extends Collection<E>> C getCollection2(CollectionSupplier<E, C> collectionSupplier) {
        return collectionSupplier.get();
    }

    public interface CollectionSupplier<E, C extends Collection<E>> {
        C get();
    }
}
```

Javac (11.0.11) compiles everything (correctly, I would say).

ECJ (4.20.0) fails to compile the `getCollection2(HashSet::new)` call with error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection to Set".

The `getCollection(HashSet::new)` call is not a problem for any compiler.

If I apply the suggested quickfix and insert a cast to `HashSet<Object>`, I get a different error from ECJ: "Problem detected during type inference: Unknown error at invocation of getCollection2(GenericsTest.CollectionSupplier<Object,Collection>)"

There are lots of similar questions here and bugs at [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=448793), but most examples seemed to involve `?`.

Comment: There are pretty few people who know the spec well enough to know for sure. In the past I've known ECJ to often be more strict (and more correct) in their interpretation of the JSL so if there was a difference, then it tended to be a javac bug and ECJ was correct. I don't know if that's still true, especially when it comes to the "new" type inference rules. I'd file a bug with ECJ, as javac is effectively the reference implementation, so it's up to them to argue if/why they are correct in differing from what it does.

Comment: @JoachimSauer `javac` is not the reference implementation and is up to the bug reporter to argue why this is a bug according to JLS. Eclipse is open source so it's _us_, not _them_.

Comment: @howlger: both OpenJDK and Eclipse are open source and I (and I suspect OP as well) aren't actively working on either, so it is "them". And yes, `javac` is not the official reference implementation, but it is the de-facto reference by virtue of being the one that's developed "closest" to the standard. Any way: both the Eclipse and the javac people will be better able to judge which one is wrong here than I am and one has to pick one (or report to both and mention the other report in both).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I agree with your on the first part of your first comment. But it is not fair to misuse bug reports to ask whether a given code is valid Java code. It's up to the reporter to argue why a bug is a bug. I encourage everyone to contribute to the open source software they use, [which can be done in many ways](https://www.eclipse.org/contribute/) and which starts by realizing that it is _us_ and not _them_.

Comment: @howlger: Of course it's up to the bug reporter to argue why they think it's wrong. I just think that "javac accepts it" is a reasonable argument. And it might *still* be a bug in javac instead of ECJ, but I'm saying I'm not qualified to judge that. And the guys at the ECJ project *are*. And I don't know why you latch onto the "them" so much: All I'm saying is that I'm not an active contributor to ECJ. I've filed bug reports with them before, but not enough to consider myself "part of the project". "Them" is not always about excluding others.

Comment: @howlger: having re-read my initial comment I see how "It's up to them to argue" could easily be interpreted in a way I didn't intend. What I wanted to say is "they will look at it and know if ECJ is wrong here or if javac is." Because *one of them* has to be wrong, as the spec is pretty specific (yes, there's a chance that the spec itself is incomplete here and both are conforming, but I don't think I've ever seen that case). I didn't mean to imply that "they have to defend themselves".

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm just concerned about the limited developer resources of Eclipse (see e.g. [here](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2021/04/05/retrospective-of-an-old-man/)) and would like to see more people contributing to open source they use. As someone answering questions about Eclipse, I consider you as an active Eclipse contributor and as part of _us_. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please report the issue you get with the cast to Eclipse JDT.

As a workaround, you can give the Eclipse compiler a hint as follows:

```
Set<Object> set2 = getCollection2((CollectionSupplier<Object, Set<Object>>) HashSet::new);
```

The tricky part for the compiler is to check whether what `getCollection2` returns is compatible to `Set<Object>`. But to be able to do that, the type parameter of the `HashSet::new` has to be known, and this is determined from `Set<Object>` (in this case, `HashSet::new` creates an instance of `HashSet<Object>`). So, the type parameter must be determined from the opposite direction than checking whether the return type is compatible with the declared type for which the type parameter is required.

It seems, Eclipse fails to compute the type parameter of `HashSet::new`. `ObjectHashSet::new` with `static class ObjectHashSet extends HashSet<Object> {}` works. `GenericsTest::newObjectHashSet` with `static Set<Object> newObjectHashSet() { return new HashSet<Object>(); }` works also, but fails with static `<T> Set<T> newObjectHashSet() { return new HashSet<T>(); }`.

Comment: I wanted to report the bug, but I was not able to log into bugs.eclipse.org either with my old account or with a new one I created now (or at least I think I created, the reset password form says it doesn't exist and the create form says it does exist).